# EC2 instance launched at terminated state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS for the first time. I created an EC2 instance. I chose the "Launch Configuration" as Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS.

But after launching it, the state is "terminated".

Following is showed in the description:

```
State Transition Reason: Server.InternalError: Internal error on launch
```

What could be the reason behind it, and how can I run the instance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is that there was an internal error (meaning, not anything you caused). Since it's terminated, you can't use it, it no longer really exists. Just launch a new instance.

If this problem keeps happening, there's something more serious happening. But that's unlikely. I find transient problems like this happen once in a while, maybe one time out of a hundred. You just got unlucky on your first try.

Comment: Thanks, i launched another one and its running.

Answer (score 2):

This can also happen when you are using a shared AMI with an encrypted volume and the KMS key used for encryption hasn't been shared with the account the AMI has been shared with.

Comment: Just to add on to this, it can also happen if you are using a shared AMI with an encrypted volume, and the KMS key used for encryption HAS been shared with the target account, but [kms grants](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/key-policy-requirements-EBS-encryption.html#policy-example-cmk-cross-account-access) have not been.

Answer (score 1):

This error can also error if you have a block device name that AWS does not expect. In my case I was trying `xvdc` but it wanted `sdc`. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential cause for this error that I just ran into was having more IPs assigned to the instances interface than was allowed for the instance size, I moved down from m5.xlarge to m5.large, which goes from 15 to 10 max IPs per interface, however I had also been considering using t3.large which actually allows 12, thus had left 12 in my configuration.

Oddly enough, the first time I tried I forgot to make that change and was still at 15 IPs and I got an error message that actually said "too many IPs for interface".

Hopefully this will help someone in the future; answering here as even though this is an old question it came up in my search and nearly everything that came up in searching suggested an issue with volumes might have seemed logical in my situation as I was launching from an AMI based on a snapshot from the original larger instance, though the search made me have doubts I couldn't see a reason why that would matter - turns out it didn't and this insanely vague error message can manifest for more than volume/block device related reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the device ids coming from existing AMI, you should pass the same in the code.

Device ID
–   /dev/sdb
–   /dev/sdc
–   /dev/sdd
–   /dev/sde

in my case, above were coming from AMI and I was passing different.